# Can't read tiff image using imread() in Octave 5.2.0 , getting this error : Magick++ exception

Tags: image-processing, octave, tiff, magick++

I downloaded Octave 5.2.0 for Image Processing, I tried to read the tiff image using imread() but I am getting this error

```
>>imread('cameraman.tif');

error: Magick++ exception: Magick: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\cameraman.tif: Null count for "Tag 34022" (type 1, writecount -3, passcount 1). (_TIFFVSetField) r
eported by coders/tiff.c:911 (TIFFReadErrors)
error: called from
    __imread__ at line 80 column 10
    imageIO at line 118 column 28
    imread at line 106 column 33
>>
```

I tried reading a JPG file and it worked fine, but I am having this trouble with tiff images

Comment: Maybe you can share the unhappy image (Dropbox, Google Drive)?

Comment: does this work? `[I,M] = imread('https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/cameraman.tif');`

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou yes it indeed worked, thanks, I think it has this problem while reading images locally.

Comment: If the imagine is the same of https://github.com/antimatter15/cameraman/blob/master/cameraman.tif that fails also on my Octave.

Comment: Update: there is some problem with this particular image, other tif images work just fine

Comment: the raw version works for me https://github.com/antimatter15/cameraman/raw/master/cameraman.tif. May be it is a wrong download

Comment: @MarkSetchell http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/image_databases/standard_test_images.zip 
images are from this source

Comment: these images are reported with errors from both ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick.

Answer (score 0):

That's because octave doesn't have these examples

try to download the image from the internet and put it in the same working directory.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30112954)